# Superscript directly above character

Tags: superscripts

In math mode, I want to typeset a beta character over an equals sign.

I've tried `$=^{\beta}$`, but that produces a superscript to the right.

[image: beta superscript]

I want the beta to be exactly *above* the equals sign. How do I do this?

Comment: Do search for `\stackrel` or `\overset` or, for that matter, the `stackengine` package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes please post that as an answer, as the accepted answer is simply incorrect.

Comment: Please note that Steven's answer is correct, while the other one isn't. Check the fact that in the `\mathop` answer the `=` sign is in a different vertical position and that spaces around it in a formula are wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, the `\overset` macro of the `amsmath` package is designed to accomplish this task.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ A \overset{\beta}{=} B \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\stackrel`, this is the syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ A \stackrel{\beta}{=} B \]
\end{document}
```

And, finally, with `stackengine`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[ A \mathrel{\stackon[1pt]{=}{\scriptstyle\beta}} B \]
\end{document}
```

For something this straightforward, `stackengine` is overkill, but it can be useful if there are multiple things to be stacked, if the vertical stacking gaps need tweaking, or if special horizontal alignments must be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ \mathop  = \limits^\beta $
```

[image]

Comment: This loses the relation spacing that `=` should have see `$ a \mathop  = \limits^\beta  b$`

Comment: This is incorrect.