# Superscript over the Gamma Function

Tags: header-footer, superscripts

I don't know how to write over Gamma function as shown in the photo. I want to write (1) (2) (3) above the Gamma function[image]

Comment: `\overset{(1)}{\Gamma}`

Comment: @egreg, post as answer?

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but since you have already asked several questions and recieved responses there that seem to answer your questions, please consider marking them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Closely related (possible duplicate?): [Superscript directly above character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215969/134144)

Comment: @leandriis I believe it is not exactly the same: in the question you linked to, the stack of two symbols is expected to behave as a `\mathrel`, and `\stackrel` is thus acceptable. I believe this is not the case here: `\overset` seems fine but not `\stackrel`.

Comment: @frougon: The accepted answer to the question I linked to also explains how to use `\overset`.

Comment: @leandriis The accepted answer says that `\stackrel` can be used as well, which would be wrong here AFAIK. Close if you want, but my opinion is that it would be confusing. Or else the accepted answer must clarify these aspects, which it didn't need to because the other question was different (it says *zilch* regarding `\mathop` vs. `\mathrel`; ditto concerning the differences between `\stackrel` and `\overset`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\overset`, but with a small correction:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\iGamma}[1]{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle(#1)}{\Gamma}}

\begin{document}

\[
\iGamma{1}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]